# How can I pass multiple json object array to stimulsoft report in Javascript

Tags: javascript, stimulsoft

I have this code in javascript:

```
var viewer = new window.Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewer(
  null,
  "StiViewer",
  false
);

var report = new window.Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
const { data: reportData } = await GetRequestFromStore(
  this.state.reportDate,
  this.state.storeId
);

var json = {
  DataSet: reportData.requestItems,
};
var dataSet = new window.Stimulsoft.System.Data.DataSet("JSON");
dataSet.readJson(json);
report.regData("JSON", "JSON", dataSet);

report.loadFile(this.state.reportName);
report.dictionary.variables.getByName(
  "requestDate"
).valueObject = this.state.jalaaliReportDate;

viewer.report = report;

viewer.renderHtml("viewer");
```

and this design of data source in stimulsoft designer

[image]

everything works well.
But I want to pass multiple json object array to the report. something like this one.

[image]

How can I pass Items object array and Descriptions object array to the report in code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataSet With Two Tables](https://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=56611) solved my problem.
I have combined the two JSON object arrays into one JSON object and register the dataset.

now, reportData is like:

```
let reportData = {
  items: [],
  descriptions: [],
};
```

[image]

and dataSet Design in Stimulsoft designer is:

[image]

and this part of code worked for me.

```
var viewer = new window.Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewer(null, "Viewer", false);

var report = new window.Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
const { data: reportData } = await GetRequestFromStore(
  this.state.reportDate,
  this.state.storeId
);

var dataSet = new window.Stimulsoft.System.Data.DataSet("DS1");
dataSet.readJson(JSON.stringify(reportData));//one JSON object

//this line of code added,too.
report.dictionary.databases.clear();
report.regData("DS1", "DS1", dataSet);

//this line of code is also required.
report.dictionary.synchronize();

report.loadFile(this.state.reportName);
report.dictionary.variables.getByName(
  "requestDate"
).valueObject = this.state.jalaaliReportDate;

viewer.report = report;

viewer.renderHtml("viewer");
```